# Downloading MNIST data from Keras results in; Error in Sys.setenv(PATH = new_path) : wrong length for argument

Tags: r, keras, path, environment-variables, setenv

I am working on Image Analysis and Classification in R.
I loaded in

```
library(tensorflow)
library(keras)
```

I tried downloading the in-built Fashion-MNIST dataset from Keras library

```
mydata <- dataset_fashion_mnist()
```

which results in the following error message

```
Error in Sys.setenv(PATH = new_path) : wrong length for argument
```

Some few days ago, I added RTools path to the Windows environment variable PATH using the following lines of code

```
rtools <- "C:\\RTools\\bin"
gcc <- "C:\\RTools\\gcc-4.6.3\\bin"
path <- strsplit(Sys.getenv("PATH"), ";")[[1]]

new_path <- c(rtools, gcc, path)
new_path <- new_path[!duplicated(tolower(new_path))]

Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(new_path, collapse = ";"))
```

I think this is what is causing the `Error in Sys.setenv(PATH = new_path) : wrong length for argument` error message when I tried downloading MNIST data from Keras.

My PATH is

```
Sys.getenv("PATH")
```

```
1] "C:\\RTools\\bin;C:\\RTools\\gcc-4.6.3\\bin;C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.0\\bin\\x64;C:/Users/Admin/Documents/R/win-library/4.1;C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\;C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\;C:\\Users\\Admin\\anaconda3;C:\\Users\\Admin\\anaconda3\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin;C:\\Users\\Admin\\anaconda3\\Library\\usr\\bin;C:\\Users\\Admin\\anaconda3\\Library\\bin;C:\\Users\\Admin\\anaconda3\\Scripts;C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Shell 8.0\\bin\\;C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Program Files\\Azure Data Studio\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.2\\bin;;C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\TinyTeX\\bin\\win32;C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_191\\bin;C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\R\\win-library\\4.1;C:\\rtools40;C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.0\\bin"
```

Please how do I solve this error?
R version 4.1.0, with RTools installed. Windows 10

`traceback` output gives:

```
13: Sys.setenv(PATH = new_path)
12: python_munge_path(python)
11: python_config(miniconda_python, NULL, miniconda_python)
10: py_discover_config(required_module, use_environment)
9: (function() {
       op <- options(reticulate.python.initializing = TRUE)
       on.exit(options(op), add = TRUE)
       py_discover_config(required_module, use_environment)
   })()
8: initialize_python(required_module, use_environment)
7: ensure_python_initialized()
6: py_config()
5: py_config_error_message(paste("Python module", module, "was not found."))
4: py_resolve_module_proxy(x)
3: `$.python.builtin.module`(keras, "datasets")
2: keras$datasets
1: dataset_fashion_mnist()
```

Please what can I do to resolve this?

Comment: After you get that error, what is the result of `traceback()`? That should show what what function is actually causing the problem.

Comment: @MrFlick please could you explain d `traceback()` output and how best to resolve it?

Comment: The traceback shows that the problem is actually being caused by the `retuculate:::python_munge_path` function which can be found [here](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/blob/9bbfdfd5ba79166773a83e0f3e2debd544204a43/R/config.R#L554). You could use `debugonce` to attach a debugger to see what's going on. The problem looks like it's coming from [this line](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/blob/9bbfdfd5ba79166773a83e0f3e2debd544204a43/R/config.R#L592). I don't use reticulate myself so I can't really debug on my own machine.

Comment: Sir, do you think the error message was caused by the RTools path created earlier?

Comment: It doesn't look like that was the likely cause. It looks like the python code it's calling isn't retuning a PATH at all.